# How to find text between [ ]

Tags: php, regex

I have a text like this

`[name:roccos] [phone:123324324] [tags:abc def ghi] [id:value]`

How can i find the values of name, phone, etc using php, So i should have variable like this `$name = 'roccos'` `$phone = '123324324'`, I can either do this for all separately or is there any way to automatically get all variables along with value automatically...

Ex : In this text `[abc:def] [phone:123456]` everything before the colon `:` will be the variable name and after the colon will be it's value => `$abc = 'def'` `$phone = '123456'`

Comment: have you considered JSON format ... ??? or you are restricted to this format ????

Comment: What have you tried so far? Introduction about regex can be found here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Since i am hopeless at Regular expressions, I taught it will be difficult.., No matter how much i try regular expressions It's always difficult for me to learn.

Comment: @Baba I am open to JSON format as well, I will try out JSON as well.

Comment: Folks, not everyone comes out of the womb knowing regex. Please hold the snarky comments. If you feel the question should be closed, use your close votes and flags. But don't berate a beginner for being a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a regular expression, and `preg_match_all`:

```
$str = '[name:roccos] [phone:123324324] [tags:abc def ghi] [id:value]';
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?):(.*?)\]/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$data = array();

foreach($matches as $match) {
    $data[$match[1]] = $match[2];
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/KbDIT)  Note that I used an array to hold the data instead of directly assigning them to global variables; that would be dangerous if you were taking this from any kind of user input. If the data is safe, you can expand it using `extract`:

```
extract($data);
```